# jekyll liquid, contains inside if loop

Tags: jekyll, liquid

Just wondering why the liquid contain statement doesn't seem to see that there's a link in the url?

YAML Front matter

```
javascript:
  - https://external.js
  - local-script.js
```

Footer file:

```
 {% if page.javascript %}
      {% for script in page.javascript %}
        {% if page.javascript contains "://" %}
        <script src="{{ script }}"></script>
          {% else %}
        <script src="{{ script | prepend: '/assets/js/' | relative_url }}"></script> cat
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

the output is

```
<script src="/assets/js/https://external.js"></script> "cat"
<script src="/assets/js/local-script.js"></script> "cat"
```

Comment: Probably one of the characters needs to be escaped. Does it work if you test for 'http'?

Answer (score 1):

The YAML front matter thinks you have created a variable called `https` with the value of `//external.js`. You can test that by calling `{{ page.javascript.https }}` and see if it returns `//external`. The solution would be to write your YAML front matter strings like this:

```
javascript:
  - 'https://external.js'
  - 'local-script.js'
```